# How can I change the back button title in ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

In Ionic Framework, I use this HTML structure on all my views:

```
 <ion-view view-title="Some title">
    <ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
 <ion-content>
```

Then I get a "< Back" button generated automatically. However, sometimes this button has the word "Back" and sometimes it has the name of the previous view.

Where and how can I change how the back button title behaves?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the `$ionicConfigProvider`:

```
var myApp = angular.module('reallyCoolApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(5);

  // note that you can also chain configs
  $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('Go Back');
});
```

This example is from the official Ionic docs.

To control the behaviour of the "last view text on back button" you could set `backButton.previousTitleText(value)` to false.

Comment: Thanks this worked nicely. Follow up question: Since I'm using a service ($transate) to translate "Go back" to the current language, my app crashes since services aren't allowed to be injected into the app.config block. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Great to hear! I think you should be able to call the backButton.text in your $translate controller as well...

Answer (score 3):

In [Ionic Framework 2](http://ionicframework.com/) you could now use the set the [config property](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/) **backButtonText** to `''`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyApp ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      backButtonText: '',
    }, {}
  )],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ MyApp ],
  providers: []
})
```