# How can i know if <ion-nav-back-button> is displayed in ionic 1.x?

Tags: ionic-framework

In a tab based ionic 1.x app, I'd like to display a customized "goBackHome" button only when the `<ion-nav-back-button>` is not displayed.

How to detect is the `<ion-nav-back-button>` is displayed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution for the current Ionic release:

`$rootScope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(e, data) {
  $scope.isBackButtonShown = data.enableBack;
});`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution from [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-detect-if-ion-nav-button-is-shown/4675):

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewHistory.historyChange', function(e, data) {
        $scope.isBackButtonShown = !!data.showBack;
    });
```

**Additionally**, it might help:

App.js - custom text and icon. You can use [$ionicConfigProvider](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/).

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

  $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(false).text('customText'); 
  $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.icon('ion-ios-home');
})
```

Controller.js - force Ionic to display back button on certain page

```
.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
  viewData.enableBack = true;
}); 

})
```

Additionally resources:

- [Change/Hide ion-nav-back-button text](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/change-hide-ion-nav-back-button-text/5260)
- [How can I change the back button title in ionic framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088250/how-can-i-change-the-back-button-title-in-ionic-framework)
- [How to force Ionic display back button on certain page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598893/how-to-force-ionic-display-back-button-on-certain-page)
- [Ionic override all BACK button behaviour for specific controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231737/ionic-override-all-back-button-behaviour-for-specific-controller)
- [hiding back button in ionic, angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333519/hiding-back-button-in-ionic-angularjs)
- [Show side menu or back button conditionally](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/show-side-menu-or-back-button-conditionally/16107/2)
- [Hide  with ng-hide/ng-show](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-hide-ion-nav-buttons-with-ng-hide-ng-show/9142)
- [Ionic - Conditionally Hiding Back Button](https://codepen.io/calendee/pen/eusfl)

Comment: $viewHistory.historyChange seems to be undefined and your reference to ionic forum points to an old version of navBackButton.js . Nevertheless successive comments in ionic forum suggest an alternative (and working solution).